# How to fix command blocks not changing settings?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’ve been working on a mini game for a while now, everything has been going smoothly until recently any command block I put down will be stuck on an impulse, always active setting despite changing the settings. Changing the setting will change the texture of the command block but it will still work the same as an impulse command block.

I’ve already tried fixing this by turning on and off cheats, leaving and rejoining world, and even closing out Minecraft entirely and relaunching it.

Answer (score 1):

After discussing it in the comments, it was found that this problem was a bug in an older version. (1.16.1)

If you are having a similar problem, try updating to the latest version of MCBE. (1.16.20)